# How to reformat a SD card to VFAT after formating it ext3

Tags: windows, linux, formatting, sd-card

I have formatted a sd card ext3 for some test but I would like to to  reformat to vfat.  I have used linux to reformat using mkfs.vfat but still can't read it in windows.  The next thing I was going to try was to dd from a good SD card but wanted to see if anyone else had a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is simply download and use Gparted either within your current Linux environment or [as a live cd from here](http://www.gparted.org). Gparted uses Vfat in order to do fat related activites and it has a good UI to make it easy.

Edit - also a little confused upon re-reading, Vfat is a general name for fat16 where as vfat is a subsystem (or program... not sure on terminology) in linux to interact with Fat based operating systems. Either way, Gparted should be able to format in fat16 or fat32.